# how to get digits of a integer from NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uipickerview

I am having a string like `NSString *str = @"123"`.I want to fill the digits of this string into UIPickerView.But how to get the digits from this string?I added the following code

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
 int number = [str intValue];
 if(component == 0)
 {

 }
 else if(component == 1)
 {

 }
 else 
 {

 }
}
```

Comment: means you want to get 1,2 and 3 separately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see this..

```
NSMutableArray *arrNumbers = [[NSMutableArray] alloc] initWithCapacity:[YOURSTRING length]];

for (i=0;i<[YOURSTRING length];i++) 
{
  unichaar ch = [YOURSTRING characterAtIndex:i];
  NSLog(@"Processing charachter %c",ch);
  // If you really want
  [arrNumbers addObject:(id)ch];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Other solutions seem to be excessive, considering NSString is already an array of characters. More lightweight solution:

```
NSString *str = @"123";
for (int i = 0; i < [str length]; i++) {
    int digit = [str characterAtIndex:i] - '0';
    // do something with your digit
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have it as a string you can just do

```
NSArray * digitStrings = [str componentsSeparatedByString:""];
```

And each element in the array would be a digit as a NSString.

Answer (score 2):

not tested but you can give it a try, this is supposed to scan all numeric entries of your string.

```
-(NSArray*)getDigitsFromString:(NSString*)str{
NSMutableString *outpuString = [NSMutableString
                                stringWithCapacity:str.length];

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];
NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet
                           characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];

while ([scanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
    NSString *buffer;

    if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:&buffer]) {
        [outpuString appendString:buffer];

    } else {
        [scanner setScanLocation:([scanner scanLocation] + 1)];
    }
}

NSArray * digitStr = [outpuString componentsSeparatedByString:@""];

    return digitStr;
}
```

Comment: If you're not sure that the string is only numbers you could do this. Don't forget to declare and alloc strippedString, I don't see you doing that.

Comment: if the string is sure to contain only numbers, I would also suggest using just the `componentsSeperatedByString` like @MrAzulay answered

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSMutableArray * digit=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSString *string = @"123456";
    for (int i=0;i<[string length]; i++) {
        NSString * newString = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];

        [digit addObject:newString];
    }
    NSLog(@"String %@ ", digit)
```

Answer (score 0):

One more answer which addresses more the idea of the original question by solving the problem of separating an int into it's digits:

```
  NSString *numberString = @"68243";
  int result[numberString.length]; 
  NSInteger number = [numberString integerValue];
  int j = numberString.length - 1;
  while (j >= 0) 
  {
    int power = pow(10, j);
    int rest = (number %  power);
    result[j] = (number - rest)/power;
    number = rest;
    j--;
  }
```